# Simple UITapGestureRecognizer. IBAction not firing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, storyboard, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UITapGestureRecognizer` linked up to an `IBAction`. I am simply trying to confirm the IBAction method call. For the `UITapGestureRecognizer`, in storyboard I have a reference outlet collection to gestureRecognizers in my View and sent action `tapGesture:` linked up to my ViewController.

.h code:

```
- (IBAction)tapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;
```

.m code:

```
- (IBAction)tapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
     NSLog(@"Tapped");
}
```

What am I missing? Why is `tapGesture:` not firing?

[image]

Comment: Is the "User interaction enabled" box checked for your view in the storyboard?  Or you can call `[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];` from the code

Comment: Yes, it is checked in storyboard.

Comment: And your `tapGesture` outlet in IB is hooked into the `selector` outlet for the gesture recognizer?

Comment: I don't think so. How do I hook it up to the selector outlet? I don't see that option when I right click the gesture in storyboard.

Comment: Look under "Sent Actions" you can also get to this list by left clicking on the gesture recognizer, and going to the last tab on the right utilities view (the tab icon looks like a circle with an arrow in it).  You should see the `selector` outlet in there.  Drag that onto your view controller and select your IBAction, and you should be good to go

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but I DID have the selector linked up to my IBAction. I didn't realize it was called `selector` until I removed the outlet under Sent Actions and saw it.

Comment: Is the tap gesture recognizer added to the view, and not just the scene?

Comment: The referencing outlet collection is set to `gestureRecognizers -> View`.

Comment: Try adding a button, and setting its touch up inside action to your `tapGesture` method, just to see if that works, and also try making a segue with the tap gesture recognizer, since that should also work.  From there we can deduce more what the problem is

Comment: Sorry for the rookie questions, but how exactly do I set its touch up inside action in my tapGesture method? I don't want to test anything incorrectly. Segue works fine by the way.

Comment: Same way I told you to hook up the `tapGesture` method to the `selector` action in IB.  Select your View Controller in IB, and drag the connector from `tapGesture` onto the button on the screen, and select `Touch Up Inside` from the list that pops up

Comment: The button IBAction does not fire either.

Comment: Oh, well actually the button probably wont.  Try changing the declaration to `-(IBAction) tapGesture:(id)sender`

Comment: Hmm well it is tough to tell what could be going wrong at this point without looking at it, could you upload a couple of screenshots of how your storyboard is laid out, connections and all?

Comment: Include the outlets for your View controller as well?

Comment: I had that originally, but must have removed it at some point. Still no luck. I updated my screenshot with new outlet.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11280/discussion-between-dan-f-and-mnort9)

Comment: I got it! It was the reference outlet collection. Like you said, it needed to be linked to the View, not the ViewController. If you can post that as your answer, I will gladly mark it as correct! Thanks again!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems from your screenshot that the gesture recognizer is added to the view controller, not the view.  You just need to drag the gesture recognizer onto the view, and it should add it correctly.